# Error loading sample dataset in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to load a sample data set [referring elastic search docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html) but when I am trying to run the instructed command, I am getting the below error. I have read all documents but I am unable to resolve it.

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @accounts.json
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "accounts.json", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.

    {
      "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [ {
          "type" : "parse_exception",
          "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
        } ],
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
      },
      "status" : 400
    }
```

[image]

First few lines in accounts.json is:-

```
{"account_number":736,"balance":28677,"firstname":"Rogers","lastname":"Mcmahon","age":21,"gender":"F","address":"423 Cameron Court","employer":"Brainclip","email":"rogersmcmahon@brainclip.com","city":"Saddlebrooke","state":"FL"}
{"index":{"_id":"743"}}
{"account_number":743,"balance":14077,"firstname":"Susana","lastname":"Moody","age":23,"gender":"M","address":"842 Fountain Avenue","employer":"Bitrex","email":"susanamoody@bitrex.com","city":"Temperanceville","state":"TN"}
{"index":{"_id":"748"}}
{"account_number":748,"balance":38060,"firstname":"Ford","lastname":"Branch","age":25,"gender":"M","address":"926 Cypress Avenue","employer":"Buzzness","email":"fordbranch@buzzness.com","city":"Beason","state":"DC"}
{"index":{"_id":"750"}}
```

I have also referred [Bulk API doc of ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

I am able to create single index but due to unknown reasons I am not able to index bulk documents.

Comment: Are you sure that the accounts.json file is in your current folder? Can you show the first few lines it contains?

Comment: I have downloaded the sample json from ES site only so i dont think there would be any error in that.

Comment: You're missing the first line which should be `{"index":{"_id":"742"}}`

Comment: the json file i have downloaded it from ES docs only the above is just random lines of data from accounts.json u can check the original json file urself from this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html

Comment: Weird as it works perfectly for me. What do you see in the elasticsearch logs ?

Comment: Are you running this from the command line or from Sense?

Comment: I have tried both used cygwin as well used postman to load a bulk data in ES but in both I got the same error.

Comment: where have you kept the accounts.json file ?

Comment: My accounts.json file is in my current folder

Comment: same i have also kept it there only.

Comment: Since you're on Windows, can you verify that you don't have carriage return characters in your file `\r`?

Comment: no i dont have any \r in my file. I have just downloaded it from the link and not modified anything in it.

Comment: If its working for you why it isn't working for me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `accounts.json` file is not available for reading, either because it has the wrong permissions/owner or because it is not in your current working directory.

First, locate the file on your filesystem, to check if it is definitely in your current working dir, type `ls -al accounts.json` (if you're using windows you should probably use `dir accounts.json /Q`) and make sure it has read permissions, then provide the full path via the curl command, for example:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary "@/home/user/accounts.json"
```

The reason I'm sure this is the issue is because I get the same error message when I try to POST a non-existing file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac OS X > Mojave / Catalina

Please check your terminal permissions.

1 Pull down the  Apple menu and choose ‘System Preferences’

2 Choose “Security & Privacy” control panel

3 Now select the “Privacy” tab, then from the left-side menu select “Full Disk 
  Access”

4 Click the lock icon in the lower left corner of the preference panel and 
  authenticate with an admin level login

5 Now click the [+] plus button to add an application with full disk access

6 Navigate to the /Applications/Utilities/ folder and choose “Terminal” to grant 
  Terminal with Full Disk Access privileges

7 Relaunch Terminal, the “Operation not permitted” error messages will be gone

- `On completion of these steps please navigate to the dir where you have placed your json file and try to run the associated curl command.`

Answer (score 0):

**Check if you have enough memory available, more than 20-30 GBs**

I was trying to load Sample Data (eCommerce orders, flight , web logs) in to my kibana. I was getting some error.
Logs showed

`[o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [/Users/xyz/Installs/ElasticSearch/elasticsearch-7.9.3/data/nodes/0] free: 15.1gb[6.4%], shards will be relocated away from this node; currently relocating away shards totalling [0] bytes; the node is expected to continue to exceed the high disk watermark when these relocations are complete`

I freed up extra 20 GB, then it worked.
Please check if you have enough memory (not sure the amout, may be more than 20-30 GB)