# Error while sending data into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

While using Elasticsearch to load datasets with curl command->

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST "localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @$shakespeare_6.0
```

Following warning is encountered->

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "$shakespeare_6.0", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "request body is required"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "request body is required"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

My data is:

```
    {"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_id":0}}
    {"type":"act","line_id":1,"play_name":"Henry IV", "speech_number":"","line_number":"","speaker":"","text_entry":"ACT I"}
```

What is the root cause of this warning? I am using 64 bit Windows 10.

Also, Please let me know what are the different ways to send the data into the elasticsearch? I am a noob.

Comment: The file `$shakespeare_6.0` does not seem to exist. Are you sure the filename is correct?

Comment: This seems the same problem as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893964/error-loading-sample-dataset-in-elastic-search

Comment: @mbuechmann yes the file name is correct. I have downloaded it from 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.x/tutorial-load-dataset.html

Comment: @markvdlaan93 The file has read permission and I also tried to run it after changing current Directory, but it didn't work.

Comment: The name of that file is `shakespeare_6.0.json`, not `$shakespeare_6.0`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided a wrong file name. The name of that file is `shakespeare_6.0.json`, not `$shakespeare_6.0`. This is the correct command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST "localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @shakespeare_6.0.json
```

This assumes that the file is in the current directory.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. I have actually typed "shakespeare_6.0.json" only.

Comment: It is working with : -
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "localhost:9200/bank/_doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary "@shakespeare_6.0.json"

But now it is showing this error. I am adding the snippet : 

 {
      "index" : {
        "_index" : "shakespeare",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "111395",
        "status" : 400,
        "error" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Rejecting mapping update to [shakespeare] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, doc]"
        }
      }
    }

Comment: You should remove the underscore before `doc`. You are now pushing to the index `bank` and not `shakespeare` anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help . This command worked for me: 
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST "localhost:9200/shakespeare/doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary "@shakespeare_6.0.json"

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.